# Starting a service on remote machines from a text file

Tags: powershell, administration, system-administration

I am having an issue where I have made a text file that contains all the machines I need to set a service on. It looks as follows:

```
 $computernames= Get-Content ".\temp\ComputerNames.txt" 


foreach ($name in $computernames){
    Get-Service -Name 'Remote Registry' -ComputerName $name | Set-Service -Status Running -StartupType Automatic -WhatIf
}
```

The main Get-service line works fine if I give it the machine's name. However, using this variable $name I am unable to get the command to work. It keeps giving me the following error:

```
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'Remote Registry'.
At line:8 char:5
+     Get-Service -Name 'Remote Registry' -ComputerName $name | Set-Ser ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remote Registry:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Add `-ComputerName $name` to `Set-Service` as well :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just gave that a shot. It does not seem to have helped. I can perform this command just fine when doing it on a singular machine but when trying to target machines from my text file than it give me an error stating that the service is not found.

Comment: have you confirmed that the text file system names are accurate AND that they have no leading/trailing non-printing or whitespace chars?

Comment: Please show us the first two or three lines of the ComputerNames.txt file. It looks as though this is not a file where each computername is on a separate line, or that maybe it is a CSV file with headers

Comment: Manually test it -- your error isn't about a problem connecting to a remote machine, it's telling you that it didn't find a service on that remote machine with the name 'Remote Registry'.  Manually run the command against the machine in question and confirm there is a service with that name on it (assuming it's windows, there should be)

Comment: Perhaps try `-ComputerName $name.trim()`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the confusion. My solution does work but the error is not indicative of the actual issue. My file contains computer names separated out by line and using the proper names. The problem was that if a machine is not on the network because it is either off or out of the office than it returns the error I stated in my original post. I didn't notice that some of the machines were definitely off or out of the office. I appreciate everyone's efforts in resolving the issue and apologize for wasting your time.